# Subsection name as right header?

Tags: header-footer

How would I be able to put the name of each subsection as a right header atop each page?

I am using the code below, but the `\rhead` command literally puts "thesubsection" atop each page!

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\rhead{thesubsection}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see if following solves your purpose:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,twoside]{article} % document class
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % MAKE IT 'subsectionmark' INSTEAD OF 'sectionmark'

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark} %%%%%%%%%CHANGE 'L' TO 'R' HERE %%%%%%
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

%\rhead{\thesubsection} %%%COMMENT THIS LINE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{OneSection}
    One two three
\subsection{MySubSection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit 1: **When one also needs chapter name on the left side header**
Please see if following works(document class is 'report'):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report} % document class-
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% 
}

%\rhead{\thesubsection}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ChapterOne}
\section{OneSection}
One two three. On first page of a chapter header doesn't appear by default.
\vfill
Two \newpage
\subsection{MySubSection}

\end{document}
```

First page of Chapter
[image]

Second page of chapter
[image]

Comment: Works perfectly +1

Comment: @Matt: I just wanted to offer a demonstration. I wasn't thinking about the standard practice.

Comment: @JanetthePhysicist: I'm glad to know that it worked for you. Happy LaTeXing.

Comment: @Tarun thank you so very much, I'm pretty new to LaTeX :) How would I be able to keep the chapter name on the left hand header too?

Comment: @JanetthePhysicist: I have edited my answer and added some minor changes. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: The Chapter part does not seem to work for me.